# How create user with admin option?

Tags: teradata

I have Teradata v16.10.0.
I want to create user with admin options: with possibility get to grant select any tables/views.

How to create such user right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no global GRANT in Teradata, you can only grant on a database level.

That's one of the reasons why there's a superuser (usually named *sysdba*) who is the root of all databases:

```
dbc
 |...
 |-SYSDBA
 |...   |-myDB
 |...   |-myOtherDB
        |-anotherDB
        |-userA   |-subDB
                  |-anotherSubDB
                  |-UserB
                  |...
```

This user is an *owner* of all databases/users below him in the hierarchy and as owner you can Grant/Revoke any right on any owned object.

Comment: How grant for User select by any Tables?

Comment: `GRANT SELECT ON myDB TO aUser`